# JQuery for Touch Slideshow in Chrome and LightCMS

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slider, touch

Ok, so I need to use Light CMS for a client's site, but I am having an issue with the slideshows on touch devices.  Touch is very important for this site and we need it to operate well in chrome.  I simply want to touch the images to scroll to the next and I just can't figure it out.  I know very little about JQuery.  I set up a basic example page with how the slideshows run in this CMS. I have googled for weeks and exhausted my self over this.  If anyone can help me figure this out I would GREATLY appreciate it!

[slideshowexample.publishpath.com](http://slideshowexample.publishpath.com)

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having? I tried the demo on a touch device, and tapping the prev/next buttons works. It's certainly not a very responsive design. But you'll need to be more specific if you'd like assistance, especially since the demo doesn't seem to have any obvious errors. It also helps to post the *specific* code that is giving you trouble, rather than asking a general question.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I need to swipe the images rather than use the buttons. I'm new here, but I think I need a custom JQuery function to tell the slideshow to recognize touch.  Just looking for direction on this.

Comment: There isn't a built in swipe event listener in JavaScript, so you're right that a jQuery plugin might be the way to go. Check out [TouchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin) or [Hammer](http://hammerjs.github.io).

Comment: touch to scroll or swipe to scroll?

Comment: swipe.  Sorry i used the wrong term here.